# Bootstrap 4 collapsable card with collapsed status icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have managed to create a collapsible card in bootstrap 4 but I would like to show an icon(arrow pointing up when collapsed and arrow pointing down when not collapsed) in the right corner of the card header to indicate the collapsed state. The code of the collapsible card is below

```
<div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
    this is the card header
</div>
<div id="demo1" class="card-body collapse">
    this is the card body
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use jquery for that:

HTML:

```
<div class="card-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
    this is the card header
  <span class="icons float-right fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></span>
</div>
<div id="demo1" class="card-body collapse">
    this is the card body
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card-header').on("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-target');
        if($(id).hasClass('show')){
            $(this).find('.icons').removeClass('fa-arrow-alt-circle-down').addClass('fa-arrow-alt-circle-up');
            console.log($(this).find('.icons').attr('class'));
        }else{
            $(this).find('.icons').removeClass('fa-arrow-alt-circle-up').addClass('fa-arrow-alt-circle-down');
            console.log($(this).find('.icons').attr('class'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.I have multiple collapsible cards on my page. Will the jquery code work for all of them or do I need to copy/paste this code for each card and change some values in it for that specific card? Also where are the icons coming from? If I need to add some resources(css files/js files) to the page can you please mention those?

Comment: it works for all of card and the **icons** is just a class there is no CSS for that, just copy and paste and see it by yourself. I don't know what icon library you're using I put Fontawesome as default.